# Get the version of a Wikipedia page from a specific date

Tags: mediawiki, wikipedia

I need to find a version of a Wikipedia page from a specific date (specifically, October 14, 2010). Is there any way to view the revision history from before a specific time/date?

Answer (score 8):

You can limit the history page to a specific date, then the first version listed is what was valid at that specified date:

Go to the history page of your desired page, and then add `&YYYYMMDDHHMMSS` to the URL.

Example:

```
http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Help:Page_history&action=history&offset=20121231000000
```

(BTW, that page is where I found this info!)

Answer (score 6):

Wikipedia has a "browse history" box at the top of each revision history box. This allows you to see the changes from before a specific year and month.